# Replacing a part of a string with null

Tags: python, pandas, string, psycopg2

I need to automate the import of an Excel-file into PostgreSQL using Python. I'm relatively new to Python but managed to automate the creation of the tables. Now I got stuck on importing the data into the  tables.

The problem I'm having is that in PostgreSQL I have defined certain columns as Date columns. However, for many of the "Date" columns there isn't any data yet. Therefore it is marked as nan. But, psycopg2 doesnt like nan as a value for a Date column and instead expects a null.
When converting the list to a string, which should be passed into the `INSERT INTO {sheet} VALUES ({formatted_data_string})`, I believe the individual entries for the Table should be in a string looking something like this: `'data', 'data', 'data', null, 'data'` The code below gets the data from the Excel-File and then creates the formatted_data_string which should be inserted into the SQL-Statement.

```
 def import_data(path):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    sheets = xl.sheet_names
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, database=database, user=user, password=password)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sheet_column_names = []
    for sheet in sheets:
        if sheet == 'ReadMe':
            continue

        df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet)
        list_of_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
        for entry in list_of_rows:
            if entry == list_of_rows[0]:
                continue

            formatted_data = []
            for element in entry:
                if element == 'nan':
                    formatted_data.append('null')
                else:
                    formatted_data.append(f"'{element}'")
            formatted_data_str = ','.join(str(element) for element in formatted_data)
            print(formatted_data_str)
```

Almost all of the data is formatted correctly except for the 'nan' values which still appear as 'nan' and not the `null` I'm expecting. I checked the code severall times but can't figure out why it's not replacing nan with null.

This is a sample of the formatted_data_str that I currently get from this code:
`'25...1','Something','XX','XX','[relToChild, relToParent]','Some Other Data','2018-10-09 06:04:28.015000','nan','1','DISABLED','nan',...`

Is there something wrong with this code. Or am I missing something obvious to get nan replaced with a null without quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem that works just fine.
Creating a second DataFrame with the following command replaces all nan with None.

```
df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet)
df1 = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

This then allows me to target the None with a For-Loop, replacing all None's with null. While adding a second single quotation arround the Data objects.

```
for element in entry:
   if element != None:
      formatted_data.append(f"'{element}'")
      continue
   else:
      formatted_data.append('null')
```

After converting the new list (formatted_data) to a string using

```
formatted_data_str = ','.join(str(element) for element in formatted_data)
```

The resulting string is in the  required format that I explained above. The SQL Statement is accepted by the Server and the data appears to be correct in the PostgreSQL DB. I know that this might not be the nicest solution but it works for me and thats all I need right now.